# "%" which not have letters 'a', 'o' and 'u' in it

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have simple SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM keys WHERE key LIKE ‘a%o%u’
```

But I want to get only this columns, where `key` have first letter "a", in center "o", last letter "u" AND between them no letters a, o and u.

Comment: When you saw o needs to be in the center, do you mean the center, or just anywhere between (either way I'd guess you need a regex for this)?

Comment: Use a Regular Expression. The REGEX gurus will be able to tell you which one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821419/regular-expression-starting-and-ending-with-a-letter-accepting-only-letters

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM keys WHERE `key` REGEXP 'a[^aou]*o[^aou]*u'
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: awesome picture, i  never seen it. (i just register on debuggex)

Comment: I get this when I launch it in PHPMyAdmin "#1139 - Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp"

Comment: @Ludwik11 Corrected it, please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Use RLIKE. I am currently on a mobile phone so cant post the full answer. You can look up mysql manual for RLIKE / REGEXP.

Answer (score 1):

What you're really looking for here is a Regex. Thankfully this can be done. Consider the following expression for your needs:

```
a([^aou]*[o]{1}[^aou]*)?u
```

That just needs to be added to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM keys WHERE `key` REGEXP 'a([^au]*[o]{1})*u'
```

And to help understand the Regex, here's the explanation and demo:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7UehkPbE6OH3H-IT)

Comment: With this "au" would be possible. And there's no possibility to have characters between o and u.

Comment: @fancyPants, be more specific please and provide me an example that breaks it and I'll get it modified.

Comment: Like I said, "au" breaks it, because there must be a "o" in there. The smallest possible string is "aou". Another example, "aoxu" wouldn't be possible.

Comment: awesome picture, i never seen it. (i just register on debuggex)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested much more but you can easily test with your data

```
like 'a[^aou]%o%[^aou]%u'
```

Comment: I think there should be "%" after "a" and before "[^aou]"

Comment: Who upvotes this? LIKE doesn't support anything except % and _ as wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this page with Pattern Matching will help you?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx

MySQL:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Comment: Does that apply to MySQL too?

Comment: Oh sorry.. I'm not sure. I saw SQL only so I assumed MS SQL :S

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

SELECT * FROM keys WHERE (key LIKE 'a%' or key LIKE '%o%' or key LIKE '%u') and (key NOT LIKE '%a%' AND key NOT LIKE '%o%' AND key NOT LIKE '%u%');

The statement doesn't make much sense to me especially the letter 'o' conditions. 1st condition says 'o' should be at the center then 2nd condition says no 'o' in between. But I guess what you want should translate to this. :)