# How to detect if a string have letters in the beginning using scala funcs or regex?

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string number that might and might not have 2 or more chars in the beginning of the number, and maybe some chars that are not letters or numbers.

If its two or more in the beginning so delete the first 2 and clean the string from chars others than letters or numberss.

I want to detect that either using scala funcs or regex and clean this string.

examples:

"ABC12345" (after function) => "C12345"

"AB12345" (after function) => "12345"

"A12345" (after function) => "A12345"

"ABC1 23 +.4 5" (after function) => "C12345"

Comment: do you mean if 2 or more chars in begining then replace it ?

Comment: @Mritunjay if its two or more in the beginning so take out the first 2

Comment: regex like this one:
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821419/regular-expression-starting-and-ending-with-a-letter-accepting-only-letters

Comment: Should `_` be kept or removed? Can there be lowercase letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex matching characters which you want to remove:

```
^[A-Z]{2}|[^A-Z0-9]
```

It matches either exactly two letters at the beginning of string or anything other than `[A-Z0-9]`.

Usage in Scala:

```scala
scala> val regex = """^[A-Z]{2}|[^A-Z0-9]""".r
regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^[A-Z]{2}|[^A-Z0-9]

scala> val ss = List("ABC12345", "A12345", "ABC1 23 +.4 5")
ss: List[String] = List(ABC12345, A12345, ABC1 23 +.4 5)

scala> ss.map(s => regex.replaceAllIn(s, ""))
res0: List[String] = List(C12345, A12345, C12345)
```